# ActivityMainBinding class does not recognize my package

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a project using MVVM.

I've enabled `dataBinding` by modifying the gradle file.

```
dataBinding{
  enabled = true
}
```

but after I build my project it doesn't recognize on of my packages.

I tried clean and restart android studio but it does not fix.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to import a whole package you should use.

```
com.example.yourpackage.*
```

In this case the compiler can understand what you are doing.

Comment: I know that.but I dont create that class.when try to build android studio create that class itself.and if I fix that next time I try to build it change it to previous code

Comment: Strange because ActivitiMainBinding should not import packages, only individual classes like "MAinViewModel".

How do you instansiate your viewmodel class in your activity or fragment? 
Are you using dagger dependency injection? If yes how your ViewModelModule works?

Answer (score 0):

If you have created Your viewModel Check the Following.

1. Have you mentioned Variable in your layout.
2. Check if you have missed typed any while binding.
3. clean and Rebuild Project
4. Goto Gradle->->app->other->dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug and run it.

This worked for my project.

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
import com.example.mvvmLogin.ViewModel.LoginViewModel;`
```

and at the declaration -

```
protected LoginViewModel mViewMOdel;
```

do the same for other activities in the packages

if you are using

```
import com.example.mvvmLogin.ViewModel.*;
```

declaration is done by

```
protected LoginViewModel mViewMOdel;
```

using protected ViewModel.LoginViewModel mViewMOdel; is not correct

Comment: I try it..it dose not fix it